# Assigning default values to generic types

Tags: typescript, generics

I am currently learning TypeScript and I was reading about how you can assign default values to generic types. For instance, for `MyGenericWithDefault`, the default value is a string. My question is, so is `myTypeWhichIsStringIfNotSpecified` also a string?

Also, does `myGeneric1` mean that the default value is now number?  While `myGeneric2` and `myGeneric3` remain as strings?  I am a bit confused as to what is going on there?
Any explanations are appreciated,

```
interface MyGenericWithDefault<T = string> {
    myTypeWhichIsStringIfNotSpecified: T;
}
const myGeneric1: MyGenericWithDefault<number> = { myTypeWhichIsStringIfNotSpecified: 1 };
const myGeneric2: MyGenericWithDefault = { myTypeWhichIsStringIfNotSpecified: "string" };
const myGeneric3: MyGenericWithDefault<string> = { myTypeWhichIsStringIfNotSpecified: "string" };
```

Comment: "is myTypeWhichIsStringIfNotSpecified also a string" --- it is whatever `T` equals to in a particular instantiated type.

Comment: "Also, does myGeneric1 mean that the default value is now number?" --- no, it's not default, it's particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interface MyGenericWithDefault` describes a format for an object.  You can create infinitely many *instances* of objects that fit your interface, and each one has its own `T`.  The `T` for each object is inherent to that object only and has no impact on other objects that use the interface.

The default value in `MyGenericWithDefault<T = string>` means that every object you apply this type to will have the value type that you provide it, like `<number>`, or `<string>` if no type is provided.

```
// T is number
const myGeneric1: MyGenericWithDefault<number> = { myTypeWhichIsStringIfNotSpecified: 1 };

// T is string
const myGeneric2: MyGenericWithDefault = { myTypeWhichIsStringIfNotSpecified: "string" };

// T is string
const myGeneric3: MyGenericWithDefault<string> = { myTypeWhichIsStringIfNotSpecified: "string" };
```

The types for `myGeneric2` and `myGeneric3` are equivalent because the value that you explicitly set is equal to the default.  Some linters will actually warn you about unnecessary generics in the case of `myGeneric3` because including `<string>` here is pointless (though it can help with readability).